# Bluetooth transmitter that can receive commands from wi-fi network?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, wifi, converters, mobile-application

I am looking into building some apps for bluetooth accessories, and wanted to know if there was some sort of device that could do the following (for sake of simplicity, lets call the "wi-fi to bluetooth" transmitter the "dongle"):

1. Dongle can connect to a wi-fi network, mobile device then sends a command over wi-fi
2. Dongle receives command from wi-fi network
3. Dongle then converts those commands and transmits out as bluetooth
4. Bluetooth accessory then receives the converted commands from dongle

I am not sure if such a device exists, but I have some great ideas for building apps that could remotely access bluetooth accessories over a wi-fi network.

Comment: I don't know of a dedicated hardware solution to this, but I know you can achieve the same using an iPhone and the new Multipeer Connectivity framework in iOS 7. Take a look at Session 708, Nearby Networking with Multipeer Connectivity from the [WWDC 2013 videos](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/)

Comment: @neilco - Thanks! I will take a look and see if this will do the trick.